# Trouble assigning a value to a variable in sql server scalar value function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which is essentially a client checklist consisting of a number of 'bit' and 'datetime' fields.  For the bit fields, a 1 is complete and 0 is not complete and the datetime fields hold information on when a particular checklist item was complete.  Each checklist item is actually a separate column.  I know that may not be the cleanest design, but it's the best I've come up with.

Now, I'm trying to write a scalar-valued function that assesses a client's progress through the checklist.  This function loops through all the columns that are of the bit type and sees how many are 1 or 0, and returns the percentage complete.

Please see the code below

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Get_ClientProgress]
(
    -- ClientID parameter refers to ClientID column in CHECKLIST Table
    @ClientID int
)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @totalRows int,
    @fieldChecked bit, 
    @colBuffer nvarchar(50), 
    @intCounter int, 
    @valueBuffer int,   -- holds the cumulative total of bit fields that are marked true in CHECKLIST Table
    @sql nvarchar(max),
    @ClientProgress float

    -- temporary table to hold column names
    DECLARE @temp TABLE
            (
                Row int,
                Column_Name nvarchar(50)
            )
    -- First, get the total number of 'bit' fields in the CHECKLIST table
    SELECT @totalRows = Count(Data_type)
                        FROM information_schema.columns 
                        WHERE data_type = 'bit' AND Table_Name = 'CHECKLIST'

    -- the purpose of @temp is just to reorganize the CHECKLIST table in a top to bottom fashion instead of left to right
    -- This makes it easier to loop through each field
    INSERT INTO @temp
        SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY Column_name) as Row, Column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns 
        WHERE data_type = 'bit' AND Table_Name = 'CHECKLIST'

    SET @intcounter= 1  -- counter used for the loop; will also hold row number
    SET @valueBuffer = 0    -- will hold the cumulative value

    -- begin loop to find how many fields are marked true
    WHILE (@intCounter <= @totalRows)
        BEGIN
            SET @colBuffer = (SELECT Column_Name FROM @temp WHERE Row = @intCounter)
            -- The next line is where I'm having trouble
            SET @fieldChecked = (SELECT (CASE WHEN @colBuffer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM [dbo].[CHECKLIST] WHERE ClientID = @ClientID)
            SET @valueBuffer = @valueBuffer + @fieldChecked
            SET @intCounter = @intCounter + 1
        END
    IF @valueBuffer is NULL
        SELECT @ClientProgress = 0
    ELSE
        SELECT @ClientProgress = CAST(@valueBuffer as float) / CAST(@totalRows as float)
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @ClientProgress
END
```

In the above code, I'm having trouble assigning a value to @fieldChecked using the SELECT statement given.  I'm just trying to get the bit value for that particular column name held in @colBuffer.  I've also tried the following statements but none of these have worked:

```
SELECT @colBuffer FROM BUYER_CHECKLIST WHERE ClientID = @ClientID
SELECT TOP 1 @colBuffer FROM BUYER_CHECKLIST WHERE ClientID = @ClientID
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN @colBuffer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM BUYER_CHECKLIST WHERE ClientID = @ClientID
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN @colBuffer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM BUYER_CHECKLIST WHERE ClientID = @ClientID
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're just selecting out the value in @colBuffer, not the anything from the column named after that value.  You'd need to create dynamic sql.  Here's an example:

```
create table #sample (
        ID int,
        colA nvarchar(100),
        colB nvarchar(100)
    )

insert #sample values
    (1, 'xxx', 'yyy')

declare @colBuffer nvarchar(100) = 'colA'

-- ONE WAY:
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
    select ' + @colBuffer + ' from #sample
    '
exec(@sql)

-- ANOTHER WAY:
select  case
            when @colBuffer = 'colA' then colA
            when @colBuffer = 'colB' then colB
            else ''
        end
    from #sample

drop table #sample
```

Comment: I previously made a stored procedure that made use of exec() and it worked fine, but I won't be able to use this inside a function.  If I could, I would stick with the stored procedure, but I need to be able to use this function in some views.

Comment: You can't reference a column name via a variable without building dynamic SQL.   If the columns are known, you could do a big switch statement. I've modified my answer to describe that.

Comment: Thanks Chris!  That makes sense why it doesn't work.  Looks like it's back to the design table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (you seem to have too many parenthesis): 
change:

```
SET @fieldChecked = (SELECT (CASE WHEN @colBuffer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

to:

```
SELECT @fieldChecked= CASE WHEN @colBuffer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  tempname FROM
```

Comment: Benjamin - tried, but not working.  I'm getting the following error (with and without the parentheses: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'COLUMNNAME' to data type int.

Comment: Now that I look at your complete statement I don't understand how this works:s SELECT (CASE WHEN @colBuffer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END from what is the purpose of the from part - you are testing the variable  colbuffer.